# Is it silly to have a pointer as a member field in a C++ class?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

I want to check I understand correctly. If I had the following in my header:

```
public Obj * objPtr;
```

and the following in a class:

```
void create() {
    //create a local variable object
    Obj localVar = object();
    objPtr = &localVar;
}

void edit(){
    //attempt to edit value of member pointer
    objPtr->edit();
}
```

Am I correct in thinking that it's never going to work? since localVar is local, it will be destroyed once outside of the create function, leaving objPtr to have the address of empty memory which means objPtr is a null pointer?

secondly, would it work if I made it:
`Obj localVar = new object()` or 
`objPtr = new object()`

Comment: You're half correct: yes it's silly. But the pointer won't be null, it will simply point to a bad location.

Comment: what exactly is a bad location?

Comment: `public OBj * objPtr;` is illegal syntax. Did you mean you had `OBj * objPtr;` in the public section of yoru class definition?

Comment: A bad location is quite literally any location that is not good, and the only good location is where the object resides in storage. If the object does not reside in storage, there are no good locations. What happens if you go looking for an object in a bad location is undefined. Could crash the program. Could mangle some data you need to use later and cause the program to stagger on alive but broken. Could do anything right down to instruct your floppy drive to eject gold coins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I correct in thinking that it's never going to work?

Only in part. You might get lucky and it might work, but the behavior is expected to be unpredictable (or more specifically, *undefined*) and is *definitely a bug* in the code.

The reason is that the content may or may not be present at the specified address anymore. The point at which the memory used for `create`'s former stack frame gets reused by the system depends on several factors, including what the program tries to do next (e.g. call another function immediately? declare more variables?) and the architecture-specific code that gets generated by the compiler for it.

If the program chooses to do something that causes it to alter the former stack frame of the `create` function (e.g. calling another function), then you end up with *undefined behavior* if you try to use a pointer to the `&localVar`.

> since localVar is local, it will be destroyed once outside of the create function, leaving objPtr to have the address of empty memory

It won't be "empty" memory. Saying it's an *invalid* address might be more accurate here. If you get lucky, you still have the previous value (the more you wait, the less likely you'll be this lucky). Get unlucky and you get garbage. Get *really* unlucky, and you get something that belongs to something else (e.g. some other variable) and can corrupt things or cause a segmentation fault.

> which means objPtr is a null pointer?

A null pointer is when the address is zero, i.e. `char *ptr = 0; // same as NULL`.

> secondly, would it work if I made it: Obj localVar = new object() or objPtr = new object()

The code above wouldn't work. You need to use pointers, but `localVar` isn't one.

If you write something like:

```
Obj *my_function() {
    Obj *ptrObj = new Obj(); // notice it's a pointer
    // ...
    return ptrObj;
}
```

Then, yes, it would work. But you should understand *why* there's a difference.

In the first case, you're placing contents in the *stack*, which gets `pop`ed after the function returns, along with the `Obj` itself. In this second case, it works because the only thing that's on the stack is the *pointer* to `Obj`, but the `Obj` instance itself is in the *heap*, which survives the stack cleanup when the function returns and local variables are removed.

Since your function is now returning the *address* to an object that was allocated in the *heap* with the `new` operator, then it'll work fine.

Just remember to `delete` the object when no longer needed to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: "The OS decides when to reuse the memory." It's actually the architecture [via the generated code] as to how long the memory isn't overwritten and, thus, briefly _may_ work as you've detailed.  Tweak this and I'll upvote as the rest is the best answer so far.

Comment: Saying the behavior is unpredictable is correct, but I would also mention that it's _undefined behavior_ to introduce some lingo.

Comment: @CraigEstey: I've updated the post. Take a quick look and let me know what you think.

Comment: @ray Layout: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/ When main calls fncA, it has a stack frame.  Here, that's create and localVar is in the memory of create's stack frame.  Upon return, the stack frame memory still has data.  It will be overlayed/overwritten by the stack frame of fncB [if we call one].  But, fncA's frame is still there intact as long as we don't execute anything that overwrites/corrupts it--the usual way is to call another fnc.  Thus, fncA's _caller_ can still deref pointer.  If caller does "push", that's a corruption, too.

Comment: Here's what I'd say: The reason is that the content may or may not be valid at the specified address anymore. It's in the memory [formerly] occupied by create's stack frame.  If the caller calls another function or executes any code that changes data in the memory range of create's stack frame, the results become UB because any such action _may_ alter localVar's value in unpredictable ways, due to it being overlayed with something unrelated (e.g. the stack frame of another function that is called after create)

Comment: @CraigEstey: Thanks for the ref. I was familiar with the memory layout, but I think I get the point. However, it seems to be more dependent on what the program chooses to do and the code generated by compiler to accomplish it rather than the architecture as you previously mentioned, unless you were thinking about the fact that a compiler for some architecture A will obviously generate different code when targetting some other architecture B.

Comment: @CraigEstey: I've made a few more edits there taking your comments into account. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @ray We're both correct.  The arch dictates what the [probable] code is gen'ed for a given C statement.  So `create(); unrelated ...; x = *objPtr;` works if "unrelated" doesn't change the child stack frame. The code _can_ be arch dependent and may corrupt on one but not another.  If "unrelated" is `fncB()`, it almost certainly does.  But, we might survive if fncB uses only args and a return (e.g. has no stack frame variables of its own).  It's all dicey [and bad].  Anyway, I think you've got enough to do the clarification

Comment: @ray Your last edit was better than what I came up with.  With suitable reward ;-)

Comment: "You might get lucky and it might work some times and not others."  This fits my definition of unlucky. Lucky is when a big, brutal and repeatable epic fail pins the tail right on the donkey for me in the lab and not creep up unseen and unheard when the plane is over the Atlantic.

Comment: @user4581301: Minor edit made. I think it's a valid point that if it ends up working, you're therefore "lucky", but not otherwise. Side-tracking, though.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I correct in thinking that it's never going to work? since localVar
>   is local, it will be destroyed once outside of the create function,
>   leaving objPtr to have the address of empty memory which means objPtr
>   is a null pointer?

Yes.  Except the pointer won't be `null`.  It will have whatever value it had.  It's just that the address it points to no longer contains an object.

> secondly, would it work if I made it: Obj localVar = new object() or
>   objPtr = new object()

Yes

Comment: `Obj localVar =new object()` won't work. `Obj *localVar =new object(); objPtr = localVar;` will work. (Yoy are right because "or" is used and one of them is correct)

Answer (score 0):

The code won't work if you attempt to dereference the pointer to the destroyed object. `objPtr` won't automatically become `nullptr`, so be cateful!

Changing to `OBj localVar = new object()` won't work, either (and it may emit compile error if `OBj` doesn't have proper constructor), but you can make it work using `objPtr = new object()` if assigning `object*` to where `OBj*` is expected is acceptable (it can be archived via `typedef`, inheritance, etc.). Be careful not to cause memory leak!

Comment: `object` may also be a function, in which case `new object()` won't work.  I know he suggested doing that but given the level of the question he might be confused about that too.